# How do I select the correct version of python from Linux Terminal

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install Azure SDK on raspberry pi. I'm following this [tutorial][1]

I am at this part where I need to select Python 3.5, but I don't know how to properly enter it into the terminal.

> You can also specify the version you want by running sudo ./setup.sh
>   [--python-version|-p] [2.7|3.4|3.5]. If you run script without
>   parameter, the script will automatically detect the version of python
>   installed (Search sequence 2.7->3.4->3.5). Make sure your Python
>   version keeps consistent during building and running.

Comment: Does `$ sudo ./setup.sh --python-version 3.5` not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command would be:

```
sudo ./setup.sh -p 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
sudo ./setup.sh -p 3.5
```

but it might not be the default python tool, you might need to add it to your path